# how to update foreign key values

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are the tables that I have,

1)Roles

```
roleId  roleName


1   Super Admin     
2   State Licensee  
3   County Licensee     
4   Vendor Licensee     
5   Driver Licensee
```

2)  Permissions

```
permissionId    permissionActivity

1   Add         SL  
2   Add         CL  
3   Add         VL 
4   Add         DL  
5   Validate    SL  
6   Validate    CL
```

3)RolePermissionDetails

```
roleId  permissionId

1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
1        5
1        6
1        7
2        2
2        3
2        8
```

here i want to update all permissionIds of 2nd roleId at a time as below :-

```
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
2 -> 5.
```

What should be the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may update as below:-

```
UPDATE ROLE_PERMISSION_DETAILS SET PERMISSION_ID=3 WHERE PERMISSION_ID=2 AND ROLE_ID=2;
UPDATE ROLE_PERMISSION_DETAILS SET PERMISSION_ID=4 WHERE PERMISSION_ID=3 AND ROLE_ID=2;
UPDATE ROLE_PERMISSION_DETAILS SET PERMISSION_ID=5 WHERE PERMISSION_ID=8 AND ROLE_ID=2;
```

this way one can create updates for any number of rows or even for more complex criteria by adding criteria after where clause.

or if comfortable with using if and case in query then

```
UPDATE ROLE_PERMISSION_DETAILS SET
    PERMISSION_ID = IF(PERMISSION_ID=2,3,PERMISSION_ID),
    PERMISSION_ID = IF(PERMISSION_ID=4,5,PERMISSION_ID),
    PERMISSION_ID = IF(PERMISSION_ID=5,8,PERMISSION_ID)
WHERE PERMISSION_ID= 2
```

or

```
UPDATE ROLE_PERMISSION_DETAILS SET
PERMISSION_ID =  CASE WHEN PERMISSION_ID=2 THEN  3 ELSE PERMISSION_ID),
PERMISSION_ID =  CASE WHEN PERMISSION_ID=4 THEN  5 ELSE PERMISSION_ID),
PERMISSION_ID =  CASE WHEN PERMISSION_ID=5 THEN  8 ELSE PERMISSION_ID) WHERE PERMISSION_ID= 2
```